# JavaScript: Calculating the time required to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to POST data to a page, and to get data back. How would I calculate the time it took from POSTing to the page, and receiving the data?

I use `jQuery.post()`, and here is an code example:

```
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
   //do something with data
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

$.post("test.php", function(data) {
   //do something with data

   var end = new Date().getTime();

   alert((end - start) + ' milliseconds passed');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var before = new Date();
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
   var timeTook = new Date() - before;
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var start = Date.now();

$.post("test.php", function(data) {
    alert(Date.now() - start);
});
```

---

*Have this at the top of your script for browser compatibility.*

```
if (!Date.now)
    Date.now = function() {
        return +(new Date);
    };
```

Comment: @Andreas: Didn't know jQuery had that.

Answer (score 1):

before your request declare a date

```
var start = new Date();
```

Then inside post callback declare another date and calculate the difference:

```
var end = new Date();
alert(end - start);
```